# Converting from 4.0.1 android to 2.3.6

Tags: android, operating-system

Is there any way to reverse my android mobile operating system from 4.0.1 to 2.3.6 ? for testing purposes

My device is Huawei Honor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device has been marketed with this version, you can certainly find the 2.3.x ROM on their site and flash on your phone. What model / brand is it?

Edit :

This is french forum with all Huawei Honor Roms (2.3.6, 4.0, CM9, ...) : http://forum.frandroid.com/topic/124560-centralisation-des-roms-conseils/

Comment: I talk about your phone, is a google nexus One, google nexus S, samsung galaxy s3, ... ?

Comment: This is french forum with all Huawei Honor Roms (2.3.6, 4.0, CM9, ...) : http://forum.frandroid.com/topic/124560-centralisation-des-roms-conseils/